# How to convert a binary file to verilog file format in svn repository?

Tags: svn, verilog

While adding a set of `Verilog` files to my SVN repository, one of them got saved as a *binary file* instead of a *Verilog file* in the repository. How do I convert the file back to Verilog format (including all the earlier revisions) in the repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess you want to track it as text files to see line changes instead of binary changes.

To set mime type of file as "text/plain":

```
svn propset svn:mime-type text/plain <list_of_verilog_files>
```

Also you could try to set "text/x-verilog" instead of "text/plain" and see if it works.

Comment: As you said , I tried changing its property . After that when I ran "svn diff" on that file I got the following message 

Index: bscan.v
===================================================================
Cannot display: file marked as a binary type.
svn:mime-type = application/octet-stream

Property changes on: bscan.v
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mime-type
   - application/octet-stream
   + text/plain

Comment: You must commit working copy to apply mine-type changes. After that you will see diffs.

Answer (score 1):

As loentar's answer shows, you can certainly change the mime-type.  But (unless subversion detects or mis-detects the file as binary) it won't even bother to set the mime-type, so I typically delete the mime-type instead:

```
svn propdel svn:mime-type <filename>
```